# How did he get this outcome?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

It's a matrix solved with least squares equations (probaly). I used some calculator but can't get his outcome. If you have a way how to get to this please explain how.

[The math on that image is:
$$A = \left[\matrix{4&3&1&0&1\cr 5&2&1&0&1\cr 4&2&1&1&1\cr 3&1&0&1&1\cr 1&1&0&1&1\cr}\right], \quad\vec b = \left[\matrix{4\cr 6\cr 6\cr 3\cr 1\cr}\right]$$
"Least Squares" of $A\vec x = \vec b$ is $\vec x = \left[\matrix{1\cr -1\cr 2\cr 1\cr 1\cr}\right]$.]

Pic related:
http://postimg.org/image/7ellc2pnl/

Comment: I can't get it, either. The matrix $A$ is invertible, and I get the solution $(1,-1,3,1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

When using the matrix as you have above, I also get $\left[\begin{array}{c}{1 \\ -1 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ 0}\end{array}\right]$

However, when I add a bias column of $1$'s, I get closer to his displayed result: $\left[\begin{array}{c}{1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\ 0.5 \\ 0.5}\end{array}\right]$

Again, the matrix used with extra bias column is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}4 &3 &1 &0 &1 &1 \\
5 &2 &1 &0 &1 &1 \\
4 &2 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\
3 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 \\
1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: What is a bias column?

Comment: Finnegan's Finagle Factor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem  "The first column is populated with ones, $X_{j1} = 1$, only the other columns contain actual data, and $n$ = number of regressors + 1)."

Comment: @Axoren : The words "bias column" don't appear on that page.

Comment: What this column does is allow us to learn a constant term that shifts the line away from the origin by some amount. This relieves the restriction that we're learning an approximation that travels through $\vec 0$

Comment: IOW, Finnegan's Finagle Factor.

Comment: @CarlHeckman A bias term is common in machine learning. It's some initial constant that does not depend on the input (a predisposition to a certain result, a bias). In the wikipedia page, it does not call it this, but it does however describe explicitly that this extra column exists. I've quoted the portion that states this. On hand, I don't have a better text to cite for this, so I used the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

Least squares of $\mathrm{A} \boldsymbol{x}  = \boldsymbol{b}$ is

$$(\mathrm{A}^\top\mathrm{A}) \boldsymbol{x}  = \mathrm{A}^\top \boldsymbol{b}$$
$$ \boldsymbol{x}  =(\mathrm{A}^\top\mathrm{A})^{-1} \mathrm{A}^\top \boldsymbol{b}$$

Comment: And when you follow that formula with the above $A$, they get different results. This isn't useful.

Comment: It is because it is the correct answer for least squares. How do you know the given answer is "correct"? I think there is row or two missing from $\mathrm{A}$ or there is a mistake in $\boldsymbol{b}$.

Comment: Your answer doesn't clarify their issues. It simply restates the mechanism they're already using.

Comment: If you plug in the given $\boldsymbol{x}$ to $\mathrm{A} \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}$ you will get all zeros except the last one, which is 1. That tells me something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The least square:

$$ f(x)=||Ax-b||^2 $$

$$ x = \arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x) $$

The minimization is usually made by the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.

The result that you have is because your matrix is ill-conditioned.